SCL line Pulled Low all the time
I have made a custom PCB with nRF52840 and Three slave Devices(IAM-20380 Gyro), (ADXL372 Accelerometer), (VCNL4040 Proximity ) Sensors. All slaves are connected to one I2C Bus When I plug only power to the PCB and no firmware uploaded the SDA line is always high(as expected because SCL and SDA are pulled high with 4.7k resistors).  But SCL line is always on 1.16V to 1.2V. I tried to add external pull up resistor to SCL line but its still at 1.16V. I also tried to pull SCL line high via software. Just as a regular gpio pull up but no change in SCL voltage at all. I have even removed Slave devices from SCL bus one by one but voltage is stick to 1.16V
Is there any possibility of short connection of SCL line with someother line?
or it can be a issue in the PCB design?
I am unable to figureout the issue yet

You need to share more details. Which nrf52840 module? What pins are you using? How have you wired everything up? PCB layout/schematic would be helpful. How are you configuring the nrf? Have you programmed the correct pin assignments? Are you using a pin in use by something else in the firmware?
